# Elasticsearch nested cardinality aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a mapping with nested schema, i am tring to do aggregation on nested field and order by docid count.

```
select name, count(distinct docid) as uniqueid from table
group by name
order by uniqueid desc
```

Above is what i am trying to do.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "samples": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "sample"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "sample": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "sample.name",
        "order": {
                     "DocCounts": "desc"
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "DocCounts": {
                     "cardinality": {
                        "field": "docid"              
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But in the result i am not getting the expected output

result:

```
"buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "xxxxx",
                  "doc_count": 173256,
                  "DocCounts": {
                     "value": 0
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "yyyyy",
                  "doc_count": 63,
                  "DocCounts": {
                     "value": 0
                  }
               }
]
```

i am getting the `DocCounts = 0`. This is not expected. What went wrong in my query.

Answer (score 1):

I think your last nested `aggregation` is too much. Try to get rid of it:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "samples": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sample"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sample.name",
            "order": {
              "DocCounts": "desc"
            }
          },
          "DocCounts": {
            "cardinality": {
              "field": "docid"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would return error. Possibly Found two aggregation type definitions in like this. I tried this already

Comment: Is it possible that `"field": "sample.docid"` could solve your issue?

Comment: i do not think so

Comment: I didn't need/use the ordered setting, but the rest of the nested aggregation worked, I just needed `"field": "sample.docid"` like @core mentioned

Answer (score 1):

In general when doing some aggregation on nested type by value from upper scope, we observed that we need to put/copy the value from upper scope on nested type when storing document.

Then in your case aggregation would look like:

```
"aggs": {
  "DocCounts": {
    "cardinality": {
       "field": "sample.docid"              
    }
  }
}
```

It works in such case at least on version 1.7 of Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse nested aggregation on top of Cardinality aggregation on DocCounts. This is because when nested aggregation is applied, the query runs against the nested document. So to access any field of parent document inside nested doc, reverse nested aggregation can be used. Check [ES Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) for more info on this.

Your cardinality query will look like:

```
"aggs": {
    "internal_DocCounts": {
        "reverse_nested": { },
        "DocCounts": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "docid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response will look like:

```
  "buckets": [
  {
    "key": "xxxxx",
    "doc_count": 173256,
    "internal_DocCounts": {
      "doc_count": 173256,
      "DocCounts": {
        "value": <some_value>
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "yyyyy",
    "doc_count": 63,
    "internal_DocCounts": {
      "doc_count": 63,
      "DocCounts": {
        "value": <some_value>
      }
    }
  },
  .....
```

Check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737246/elasticsearch-nested-aggregation-with-cardinality-on-another-field/48765780)

Comment: Thanks..Improved the answer